# How to avoid Hitting the 10 sec limit per user

Tags: google-bigquery

We run multiple short queries in parallel, and hit the 10 sec limit.

According to the docs, throttling might occur if we hit a limit of 10 API requests per user per project.
We send a "start query job", and then we call the "getGueryResutls()" with timeoutMs of 60,000, however, we get a response after ~ 1 sec,  we look for JOB Complete in the JSON response, and since it is not there, we need to send the GetQueryResults() again many times and hit the threshold, that is causing an error, not a slowdown. the sample code is below.

our questions are as such:
1. What is a "user" is it an appengine user, is it a user-id that we can put in the connection string or in the query itslef?
2. Is it really per API project of BigQuery?
3. What is the behavior?we got an error: "Exceeded rate limits: too many user/method api request limit for this user_method", and not a throttling behavior as the doc say and all of our process fails.
4. As seen below in the code, why we get the response after 1 sec & not according to our timeout? are we doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot

Here is the a sample code:

```
while (res is None or 'jobComplete' not in res or not res['jobComplete']) :
           try:
               res = self.service.jobs().getQueryResults(projectId=self.project_id,
                       jobId=jobId, timeoutMs=60000, maxResults=maxResults).execute()
           except HTTPException:
               if independent:
                   raise
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that even though you specify timeoutMs=60000, it is returning within 1 second but the job is not yet complete? If so, this is a bug.

The quota limits for getQueryResults are actually currently much higher than 10 requests per second. The reason the docs say only 10 is because we want to have the ability to throttle it down to that amount if someone is hitting us too hard. If you're currently seeing an error on this API, it is likely that you're calling it at a very high rate.

I'll try to reproduce the problem where we don't wait for the timeout ... if that is really what is happening it may be the root of your problems.

Comment: thanks.if it works like that, then great.
But yes, we get the response with no job completed very fast, and need to re query.
Also, if this is throttling , how come we get the error Exceeded rate limits: too many user/method api request limit for this user_method?

Will be great if you could repro.

Comment: I've added a more detailed test, see my next comment

Comment: Can you verify that you're not getting an error on your job? Can you print out the whole result when you wait? When there is an error, you won't jobComplete, you'll just get back a different http response code and an 'error' object as the result).

Answer (score 0):

```
def query_results_long(self, jobId, maxResults, res=None):
        start_time = query_time = None
        while res is None or 'jobComplete' not in res or not res['jobComplete']:
            if start_time:
                logging.info('requested for query results ended after %s', query_time)
            time.sleep(2)
            start_time = datetime.now()
            res = self.service.jobs().getQueryResults(projectId=self.project_id,
                    jobId=jobId, timeoutMs=60000, maxResults=maxResults).execute()
            query_time = datetime.now() - start_time
        return res
```

then in appengine log I had this:

```
requested for query results ended after 0:00:04.959110
```